# Openni_tracker crashes with a segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: openi-tracker, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any idea on what is causing it ? It is running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, ROS Fuerte and an intel graphics card.

gbd run output :

```
     (gdb) run
    Starting program: /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/bin/openni_tracker 
    [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
    Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
    [New Thread 0x7ffff1038700 (LWP 8120)]
    [New Thread 0x7ffff0837700 (LWP 8121)]
    [New Thread 0x7fffebfff700 (LWP 8122)]
    [New Thread 0x7fffeb7fe700 (LWP 8127)]
    [New Thread 0x7fffdf623700 (LWP 8133)]
    
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x00007fffe8a56e56 in Segmentation::detectionByPoint(bool, std::vector<Vector2D<int>, std::allocator<Vector2D<int> > > const*) ()
       from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so


BT output :
#0  0x00007fffe8a56e56 in Segmentation::detectionByPoint(bool, std::vector<Vector2D<int>, std::allocator<Vector2D<int> > > const*) ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
#1  0x00007fffe8a61b61 in Segmentation::update(Array2D<unsigned short> const&, MotionDetectorByEdges const&, Floor const&, Farfield&, std::vector<Vector2D<int>, std::allocator<Vector2D<int> > > const*) ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
#2  0x00007fffe8a4769b in SceneAnalyzer::Update(std::vector<Vector2D<int>, std::allocator<Vector2D<int> > > const*, unsigned int) ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
#3  0x00007fffe8a0f95e in XnVSceneAnalyzer::InitFromSM() ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
#4  0x00007fffe8a107cb in XnVSceneAnalyzer::UpdateData() ()
   from /usr/lib/libXnVFeatures_1_5_2.so
#5  0x00007ffff6d315b7 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff6d3173e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0
#7  0x00007ffff6d316b3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0
#8  0x00007ffff6d31965 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff6d31c0a in xnWaitAndUpdateAll () from /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0
#10 0x000000000040346b in WaitAndUpdateAll (this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/ni/XnCppWrapper.h:9347
#11 main (argc=1, argv=<optimized out>)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker-0.1.3/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-tracker/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_tracker/src/openni_tracker.cpp:190
```

It also usually happens after I run it once succesfully. The first time it always runs OK, after that it may work once more, but the next will always segfault. After a reboot the same procedure occurs.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64929/openni_tracker-crashes-with-a-segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)./) by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2013-06-12**:
Can you post the backtrace?

**Comment by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on 2013-06-12**:
Edited for BT and some details

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-12**:
I have the same problem than you, more details about when you get this error in my post : http://answers.ros.org/question/62873/openninite-segmentation-fault-with-openni_tracker/ but I didn't get any answer...

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2013-06-13**:
Since the first time it runs well, maybe the process XnSensorServer does not close properly. After closing the program, try to kill the XnSensorServer.

**Comment by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on 2013-06-13**:
Thank you for your suggestion, I haven't been able to test it yet due to a power outage though. As soon as I can I will and post the results !

**Comment by [AndreasLydakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/5125/andreaslydakis/) on 2013-06-17**:
That actually seems to work ! I have been testing it for about an hour so far and it seems to do the job ! Thanks a bunch rastaxe ! BTW how do I mark this as solved and your answer as the solution  ?

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2013-06-17**:
I am happy this works for you. I will put my comment directly in the answer section and you can set it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since the first time it runs well, maybe the process XnSensorServer does not close properly. After closing the program, try to kill the XnSensorServer.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-06-18**:
This doesn't solve the problem for me... The problem is solved only if I re-plug the Kinect, which is not a good solution...